# Simple array display issue

Tags: matlab

I want to display values inside matrix 'inline'. Example:

```
 A = [1;2]
```

and I expected output like this:

```
X, Y = 1,2
```

I tried to do something like this but it doesn't works:

```
prinf('X, Y = %s,%s', A(:,1))
```

Comment: `fprintf` not `prinf` (and probably %d instead of %s)

Answer (score 0):

If you know your matrix has two lines than you can use your approach but I don't know any other way than to specify both variables one after the other :

```
A = [ 1; 2 ];
fprintf( 'X, Y = %g, %g\n', A( 1, 1 ), A( 2, 1 ) );
```

If, as your use of the A( :, 1 ) suggests, you do not know how many lines that matrix contains and you just want to output it you might be better off with the `disp` command :

```
A = [ 1; 2 ];
disp( A );
```

I hope this helps,

Tepp.